# Evaluate $ \int_{\gamma} (z + \frac {1}{z - 1}) \, dz $ where $ \gamma $ is the perimeter of the parallelogram with vertices $ i, -i, 2 + i, 2 - i $

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-integration

I'm learning about the theory of integration in the complex plane and need to verify my work to this problem since my textbook is using a different method of resolution :

$ $

> Evaluate the line integral $$ \int_{\gamma} (z + \frac {1}{z - 1}) \, dz $$ where $ \gamma $ is the perimeter of the parallelogram with vertices $ i, -i, 2 + i, 2 - i $.

$ $

Here's my attempt :

$ $

$$ \int_{\gamma} (z + \frac {1}{z - 1}) \, dz = \int_{\gamma} \frac {z ( z - 1 ) + 1}{z - 1} \, dz =  \int_{\gamma} \frac {z^2 - z + 1}{z - 1} \, dz = \int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{z - 1} \, dz $$

$ $

Since the function $ f(z) = z^2 - z + 1 $ is analytic within and on $ \gamma $ and since the point $ z_0 = 1 $ is interior to $ \gamma $, *by Cauchy's integral formula* it follows that

$ $

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{z - z_0} \, dz = 2 \pi i \, f(z_0) \Rightarrow \int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)}{z - 1} \, dz = 2 \pi i \, f(1) = 2 \pi i $$

$ $

My textbook however is giving a different method of resolution with a similar result :

$ $

$$ \int_{\gamma} (z + \frac {1}{z - 1}) \, dz = 2 \pi i \, \text{Res}_{z=1}(z + \frac {1}{z - 1}) = 2 \pi i  $$

$ $

Apparently the author is using *Cauchy's residue theorem* to evaluate the given line integral. Does this makes my method of resolution false? If not, is there any advantage of using one method over the other in this case?

Comment: Both methodologies are viable, both are related to the same underlying principle (Cauchy's Integral Theorem), and both are related to [Green's Theorem in the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Theorem) via the Cauchy Riemann Equations.

Comment: Both methods will give you the right answer (provided you do the calculations correctly of course). The method to use depends on the complexity of the integrand. In your case, the function is simple and so Cauchy's Integral Formula is probably the way to go.